# Quartz Scheduler Worker Threads Issue

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a problem with Quartz Scheduler worker threads. I created a scheduler task and it will execute for every 3 hours. I created one job and one trigger. When I executed this scheduler I observed a weird behavior the same job was assigned to 10 worker threads. These 10 worker threads are executing the same code 10 times. How can I solve this issue...?

Can anyone please help me on this. I am very new to Quartz Scheduler.

Thanq In Advance,
Amar

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Answer (score 2):

From the [quartz manual](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html#configuration-of-threadpool-tune-resources-for-job-execution) under the **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount** header

> If you only have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then 1 thread
>   is plenty! 
>   If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many firing every minute,
>   then you probably want a thread count more like 50 or 100 (this highly
>   depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform, and your
>   systems resources!).

This is how threadCount can be changed .

```
<configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>

<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="80" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
</quartz>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check out your cronExpression like "0 0 */3 * *"

Or change your threads count.

```
<property name="quartzProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10"/>
    </map>
</property>
```